# Populating a list with lm objects

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I am trying to populate a named list with the results of an OLS in R. I tried

```
li = list()
for (i in 1:10)
    li[["RunOne"]][i] = lm(y~x)
```

Here `RunOne` is a random name that designates the fitting run one, `y` and `x` are some predefined vectors. This breaks and gives me the error

```
Warning message:
In l[["RunOne"]][1] = lm(y ~ x) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Though I understand the error, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two solutions (depending on exactly what you want to do).

1. Create a list, and add an `lm` object to each element:

   ```
   li = list() 
   for (i in 1:10) 
       li[[i]] = lm(y~x)
   ```
2. Have a list of lists:

   ```
   li[["RunOne"]] = list()
   for (i in 1:10) 
       li[["RunOne"]][[i]] = lm(y~x)
   ```

Typically, single brackets `[ ]` are used for vectors and data frames, double brackets are used for lists.

Comment: in other words, the critical issue is indexing by double brackets `[[]]` rather than single brackets `[]`