# In R, how can I create a list or vector of lm objects so that I can then create a list of R^2 squared values?

Tags: r, statistics

I tried doing this

```
fits = list(fit0)

for(i in 1:5)
{
    temp = assign(paste0("fit", i), lm(formula = y ~ poly(x, degree = i, raw = TRUE)))
    fits = append(fits, temp)
}
```

which seems like  it should work and I don't get any errors initially.  The problem though, is that instead of creating a list of lists of length 6, where each element is itself a list (as lm objects are lists), it seems to be taking the elements of each list and making them each a separate element in temp.  When I do `length(fits)` it gives 61.  And when I do `View(fits)` it shows me this:

[image]

which certainly looks like it took all the elements of each individual list and made them the elements of `fits`, though I don't understand why.

Oddly though, if I just do `fits[1]` in the console it gives

[image]

which is the exact same output I get if I type `fit0` in the console.  So it *seems* like it's in someway storing each lm object as one thing.

The problem though, is that if I then try to get the R^2 value for, e.g., fit0, it works fine if I do `summary(fit0)$r.squared`, but if try to do it for `fits[1]` it does this:

[image]

I don't understand what's going on here.  I thought maybe the problem was using `append`, since I'd previously only used it with vectors so I Googled "how to create list of lists in R" but the examples I found used `append` so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

I assume it's something to do with the intricacy of lm objects, but the documentation isn't actually helpful (on a side note, why IS R's documentation so terrible anyway?  Compared to Python, or even C++(which is a far more complicated language to work with overall), it's so much harder to gleam the details of how the different functions and data types work because the documentation always seems to give the bear minimum, if that, of information) so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried Googling how to create a list of lm objects and I found the lmlist data type documentation, but that seems to be for when you want to create a single regression but using data grouped by categories in a data.frame, which isn't what I'm trying to do here.  I also found this post: [Populating a list with lm objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444524/populating-a-list-with-lm-objects), but I don't really understand the example code the OP asks about as I'm unsure what they mean by a "random name" or how it even even makes sense for them to be trying to access a named element in what looks like am empty list, and the only answer does the same thing.  I did make note of the comment mentioning using double brackets, but I get the same error whether I use double brackets or not:

[image]

I'm quite confused here, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It will be dramatically easier to help if you can 1) make your example reproducible so we don't have to make our own fake data and wonder if it happens to have the salient properties of your data.  2) paste in the code and errors as text instead of pictures, which we can't run or google and which can't be indexed by SO for other people's searching benefit.

Comment: You should not check R-squared values for models with polynomials of increasing degrees of freedom. The R-squared values will always increase. It would be much better to fit a smoother with `mgcv::gam` and let it estimate the smoothness. (On the technical site: forget `assign` for now and learn to work with lists properly. You can fix your code with `fits = append(fits, list(temp))`.)

Comment: @Roland, this was part of a HW assignment that required me to get the R^2 values.  The next part of the problem required getting the Bayesian information criterion for each model and noting which BIC value was smallest in contrast to the first part which required noting which R^2 was largest.  That said, I don't believe it's true that R^2 will always increase with number degree of the polynomial.  I remember a model a few months ago where I kept increasing the polynomial until R^2 started decreasing, which it did at something like a degree of 11.  But yeah, R^2 isn't always the best measure.

Comment: @JonSpring, thanks for the heads up.  I actually figured out the problem at this point, but I'll try make things clearer for future posts.

Comment: R-squared cannot decrease if you increase the number of parameters of a linear model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing how to use a `for` loop for this:

```
DF <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))

fits <- list(fit0 = lm(y ~ 1, data = DF))

for(i in 1:5)
{
  fits[[paste0("fit", i)]] <- lm(formula = y ~ poly(x, degree = i, raw = TRUE), data = DF)
}

sapply(fits, \(x) summary(x)$r.squared)
#      fit0       fit1       fit2       fit3       fit4       fit5 
#0.00000000 0.06441347 0.07915820 0.08547018 0.08547089 0.08569820
```

From the perspective of a statistician, you should not do this.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  
What does the `\(x)` do?

Comment: It's the same as `function(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

`lm` objects in R are indeed complicated. The `broom` package offers a consistent way to convert model objects into a "tidy" output format that can be easier to work with downstream.

For instance, we can use `broom::glance` to get a table with the lm stats as a data frame:

```
fit <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)
broom::glance(fit)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 1 × 12
  r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic  p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC deviance df.residual  nobs
      <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <int> <int>
1     0.753         0.745  3.05      91.4 1.29e-10     1  -80.0  166.  170.     278.          30    32
```

---

We could extend this to an example where we group the `mtcars` dataset by `gear`, nest the associated data for each gear group, run `lm` on each one, `glance` each of those, and finally unnest to get the results into a table. That seems to demonstrate what you're describing -- we can see how the `r.squared` varied for the `lm` run on each group.

```
library(tidyverse); library(broom)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(fit  = map(data, ~lm(.x$mpg~.x$wt)),
         tidy = map(fit, glance)) %>%
  unnest(tidy)

# Groups:   gear [3]
   gear data               fit    r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic  p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC deviance df.residual  nobs
  <dbl> <list>             <list>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <int> <int>
1     4 <tibble [12 × 10]> <lm>       0.677         0.645  3.14      21.0 0.00101      1 -29.7   65.4  66.8    98.9           10    12
2     3 <tibble [15 × 10]> <lm>       0.608         0.578  2.19      20.2 0.000605     1 -32.0   69.9  72.1    62.3           13    15
3     5 <tibble [5 × 10]>  <lm>       0.979         0.972  1.11     141.  0.00128      1  -6.34  18.7  17.5     3.69           3     5
```

---

Or maybe you have your list of `lm` objects, you could feed those into `map_dfr(glance)` to get a table with `r.squared`:

```
fit1 <- lm(mpg~wt, mtcars) 
fit2 <- lm(mpg~cyl+wt, mtcars)

list(fit1, fit2) %>%
  map_dfr(glance)


# A tibble: 2 × 12
  r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic  p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC deviance df.residual  nobs
      <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <int> <int>
1     0.753         0.745  3.05      91.4 1.29e-10     1  -80.0  166.  170.     278.          30    32
2     0.830         0.819  2.57      70.9 6.81e-12     2  -74.0  156.  162.     191.          29    32
```

Comment: Thanks for much the information and detailed examples!  I didn't know about the broom library.  Unfortunately, I don't think I can use it on the HW assignment that prompted this question because it's in a version of Jupyter Notebook that's on a server run by my school and it has a limited number of libraries available.   But it's still really helpful to know about this for future reference, as this isn't the first I've had trouble dealing with the messy structure of lm objects and I doubt it'll be the last.